# How to mount nested react component on a specific node?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have simple nested React component. I am nesting `HelloWorld` inside `Button`. But I would like to mount HelloWorld on a specific div (ie.on 'hello' id). Is it possible?

index.html

```
<body>
    <div id="hello"></div>
    <div id="btn"></div>
 </body>
```

jsx

```
var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <b>Hello World!</b>
        )
    }
});

var options={
    txt: "I'm Getting there!",
    counter: 10
}

var Button = React.createClass({

    handleClick: function(){
        alert('you clicked');
    },

    render: function(){
        return  <div>
                    <button onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.options.txt}</button>
                    <i>{this.props.options.counter}</i>
                    <HelloWorld/> //can I mount this on hello?
                </div>
    }
});


ReactDOM.render(<Button options={options}/>, document.getElementById("btn"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, but not directly as in your code: You cannot mount a react component outside of the root react container.

**Option 1** (this is more or less standard practice)
Create 1 react container and mount everything in there:

index.html:

```
<body>
    <div id="myApp"></div>
</body>
```

App.js:

```
var MyApp = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
              <HelloWorld />
              <Button options={this.props.options} />
            </div>
        )
    }
});

// other code unchanged..

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp options={options}/>, document.getElementById("myApp"));
```

**Option 2 (not recommended)**
Alternatively, you can create 2 completely separate react containers. Please note that these react containers cannot communicate with eachother in react-framework language.

(index.html unchanged).

app.js

```
// (other code unchanged) ...
ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld />, document.getElementById("hello"));
ReactDOM.render(<Button options={options}/>, document.getElementById("btn"));
```

PS: I left out the option var in the examples code, to focus on your question.